# what are the efficient ways to perform search operation on multiple columns in a SQL table

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, search

how to search records from SQL table which has a large data.
Also, I want to search in every column from the table whether the search string exists or not.
can I use any third party tools or azure search functions for this

Comment: It depends on what kind of data you want from the table. Cannot be generalized so easily.

Comment: I want complete row if any one of the column's value  contains the search string and the columns are of different datatypes

Comment: like is there anyway to send the bunch of data to third party tool and get the search result from that or is it efficient if i do it in sql itself

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Are you using Elasticsearch or a relational DB such as mysql?

Comment: i am using sql and want to use elastic search